# Faculty stop responding after reaching out for interview

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, interview

This Thursday, I received an email from a faculty member from an applied math program at a top U.S. university at around 5:00 AM (I'm in the U.S. so there shouldn't be a huge difference in time zone between us). He suggested that he considers me a strong applicant and would like to have a quick chat about my application "today", i.e. on Thursday. I replied around noon informing him that I am available at any time and asked him to send me a Zoom link or something after he decided on the time slot. No response. On Friday morning I sent another email telling him we can meet on Friday or early next week. Still no response.

I know a professor's daily life can be quite busy, but this still feels weird because he is the one who reached out, and he even asked for a meeting "today" which implies that the meeting/interview is quite urgent, but now he just disappears. I have no clue what's going on: did he somehow lose interest in my application? More importantly, is there anything I can do at this time?

Comment: There's probably not much you can do. Perhaps try to find his telephone number. Perhaps try to reach him through an administrator in his department.

Comment: This doesn't sound answerable, but my sympathy for the nervousness the application process can generate.

Comment: There may be a possibility that your e-mails are getting into his spambox. So try to get in touch via alternative means. Perhaps, through his or her department administrator.